# Hashing with open adress given two hash functions

Tags: data-structures, hash

I have the sequence of elements: `S = {1, 17, 8, 12, 9, 10, 8}` and I have to arrange them by hashing with open address with hash functions `h1(x) = xmod7` and `h2(x) = 1 + (xmod3)` and `m = 7`.

```
h1(1) = 1mod7 = 1   -> [   ][ 1 ][   ][   ][   ][   ][   ]
h1(17) = 17mod7 = 3 -> [   ][ 1 ][   ][17 ][   ][   ][   ]
```

Now `h1(8) = 8mod7 = 1` but that causes collision so I have to use the second hash function that gives `h2(8) = 1 + (8mod3) = 3` but that causes collision too, so where should I store the element `8`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- chain objects if a collision occur in the second hash

Or -

- choose a sequence of hash functions, not just two. If a collision occurred with the `i`th function, hash with the `i+1`th function. Read more about double hashing [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing)